# Convert list of objects to string in one line

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of objects that implement `ToString()`. I need to convert the whole list to one string in one line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Another method that may help out is `string.Join()`, which takes a set of objects and will join them with any delimiter you want. For instance:

```
var combined = string.Join(", ", myObjects);
```

will make a string that is comma/space separated.

Comment: Tried this, refused by compiler due to objects not being strings. Docs seem to say this will never work, requires strings, not objects? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The original question mentions that the objects implement `ToString()`. So, you'll either have to add `ToString()` functionality to the input classes (if you can), or you can just use linq to project the objects to `string`s, a la `string.Join(", ", myObjects.Select(a => MyStringMethod(a)));`.

Comment: Also, [the documentation does show an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes in `Object[]` for the second arg. So, assuming `myObjects` is an array, it will work for straight-up `Object`s

Answer (score 27):

Assuming you mean your objects implement ToString, I believe this will do it:

```
String.Concat( objects.Select(o=>o.ToString()) );
```

As per dtb note, this should work as well:

```
String.Concat( objects );
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828.aspx

Of course, if you don't implement ToString, you can also do things like:

```
String.Concat( objects.Select(o=>o.FirstName + " " + o.LastName) );
```

Comment: `.Select(o=>o.ToString())` is unnecessary, as the [String.Concat method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828.aspx) has an overload that accepts an IEnumerable<T> and applies `.ToString` to each item. The method also properly deals with `null` values which your solution doesn't.

Comment: and with delimiter like ***,*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Use `String.Join` instead of `String.Concat`.  If you look it up you'll see it has an extra parameter to specify delimiter.

Answer (score 10):

None of these worked for me. I'm confused, because the docs explicitly say they won't work (require string, not object). But modifying @Adil's original answer (found by looking at the previous revisions), I got a version that works fine:

```
string.Join( ",", objectList.Select(c=>c.ToString()).ToArray<string>())
```

EDIT: as per @Chris's comment - I'm using Unity's version of .NET. I used the Microsoft docs as reference, so I'm still confused why this got downvoted, but ... maybe it's a Unity-specific problem that needs this solution.

Comment: This worked from me in Unity where the other answers did not.

Comment: I'm using EF so I don't have access to a ToString method I can implement. Your solution worked perfectly with a slight tweek. Here's my method: return string.Join(", ", skills.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray()); - Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 8):

You can use [**String.Join**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to concatenate the object list.

```
string str = String.Join(",", objects);
```

Comment: `.Cast<string>()` does work if the object isn't already a string. And `.ToArray()` is unneccessary, as the String.Join method accepts an IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: `.Select(c=>c.ToString())` is unnecessary, as the [String.Join method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) has an overload that accepts an IEnumerable<T> and applies `.ToString` to each item. The method also properly deals with `null` values which your solution doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq [Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) to select a string object and [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0) into a string.

```
string StringConcat = ObjectList.Select(x => { return x.StringValue; }).ToList().Aggregate((a,b) => $"{a},{b}");
```

Example structure:

```
ObjectList = List<ObjectClass>();

public class ObjectClass {
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```